# Order bars in descending order while showing percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to create a barchart that shows how often (in percentage) each 'type' of a categorical variable appears in the dataset. I want the bars to be ordered in descending order.

Using this reproducible example:

```
data <- chickwts %>%
  group_by(feed)

ggplot(data = data, ) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = feed, y = stat(count)))
```

Now I would like the bars to be ordered in descending (or ascending) order, i.e., 'soybean' should be shown on the left, followed by 'casein', 'linseed' and 'sunflower', and 'horsebean' should be on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `geom_col` after creating a column for counts.

Since I could not replicate your result(please provide a reproducible example next time), I made a simple example using the `iris` data set.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#creating the data
data <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(mean_slength = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  ungroup()

data
"# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Species    mean_slength
  <fct>             <dbl>
1 setosa             5.01
2 versicolor         5.94
3 virginica          6.59"
```

Then I simply plot a bar graph using the `geom_col` function. The code below will accidentally generate a graph in an ascending order.

```
ggplot(data = data, ) +
  geom_col(aes(x = Species, y = mean_slength, fill = Species))
```

Let's create a graph in a descending order.

```
ggplot(data = data, ) +
  geom_col(aes(x = reorder(Species, -mean_slength), y = mean_slength, fill = Species))
```

This will create a graph shuffling the x-axis in the descending order of the y-axis values.

I hope this helps and please choose my answer if it solved your problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! This doesn't solve exactly my problem. I don't want the heights of the bars to show the values in the data, but to make the height of the bar proportional to the number of cases in each group. So I think I need to use geom_bar(). Replacing geom_col with geom_bar() shows me how many times each species appears in my data (this is fine), but I now want to order them in descending or ascending order. In this example, it doesn't really make sense as all species types appear the same number of times.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution that works:

```
data <- chickwts %>%
  group_by(feed) %>%
  summarize(cnt=n()) %>%
  mutate(props = round(cnt / sum(cnt), 2))

ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = reorder(feed, props), props)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip()
```

[image]